# Webapi is ported to IIS returns a 404 Resources not found

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-404

I have created a webapi that has been successfully tested on my development box using Visual Studio (2017) internal web server.

I have ported the webapi onto a Server hosting IIS 8.5. I have created two websites one called Downtime and another called Downtime Data. Downtime root points to CSF1Downtime that contains the webapi and it all works as expected. The root of Downtime Data contains a folder called CSF1Downtime. CSF1Downtime  has been converted into an Application.

The problem is that when I call any webapi calls Downtime Data returns a 404 resource not found error.
e.g //myserver:8080/getStuff - returns data, but //myserver:8081/CSF1Downtime/getStuff returns a 404 resource cannot be found error. But //myserver:8080/ and //myserver:8081/CSF1Downtime both work displaying a basic webpage.

To clarify, both websites are pointing to the same source folder.

Below is part of my webconfig

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>

  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
</handlers>
```

Any ideas?